# how to set paper height in TM-P60II based on html content height?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, printing-web-page

I have developed billing info label using HTML where the width is **58mm** and height is **150mm**.

If I give a print to HTML, in the print window paper size is coming **"RollPaper 58 x 297 mm"**.

[image]

so its taking paper size **"RollPaper 58 x 297 mm"** and paper wastage is happening because my page height is only **150mm.so 143mm** height paper is coming empty.

How to resolve this?
is there any way to set paper height from javascript or I have to set it from printer settings?

Thanks in advance.